# How to set a responsive background image (auto-resize in window) with css?

Tags: css

I want my background image like a Wallpaper. But I need some help to do it with css. 
Here is my css:

```
#wallpaper{
position: absolute;
background-size: cover;
background-image: url(C:\Users\Pedro\Desktop\ASK2DOC landing_page\wallpaper.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
top: auto;
left: auto;
right: auto;
height: auto;
}
```

Comment: AFAIK you can't do so purely with CSS

Comment: try setting the `height` to `100vh` and `width` to `100vw` in the CSS. Also, why do you have left AND right values in the CSS? And also @apparatix you're wrong about that, you most definitely can

Comment: @Markasoftware You're probably right, my CSS knowledge is quite poor :)

Comment: What do you mean by "like a Wallpaper"?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following :

```
#wallpaper {
    background: url(/*image_path*/) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

If it's doesn't work, click [here](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/).

Comment: this works, but the OP seems to want the element to fill the screem, I would probably opt to set the `height` and `width` to the `100%` or `100vh` and `100vw` to make it fill the scree

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cover the entire screen, you can simply do:

```
body {
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url(/wallpaper.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

The image should be in a default directory for this website.